# How to display output of a chained process in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, wps

Is there a way I can display the inputs of a WPS process when one of the inputs is output of a chained configured process ?

Maybe the snippet below will explain what  I am trying to do

```
int1=client.getProcess('local','JTS:intersection');
int1.execute({
inputs: {
a: resp.features,
b: bufproc.output()//want to display/get the output of bufproc-the chained process 

},
success: function(outputs)
{
console.log("First chaining is  succesfull");           
console.log("trying to access--"+int1.description.dataInputs[0].data.complexData.value); //[0]=input a, able to get this geometry 
console.log("trying to access--"+int1.description.dataInputs[1].data); //[1]=input b,not able to get this geometry --prints undefined
console.log("Added result of chaining to res");
map.addLayer(layerres);

}
});
```